# How to compute the maximum series of a specific condition returning true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

i have a slight issue to count the MAX frequency of where the third colmn is bigger than the second. This is just a statistic with scores. 
The issue is that i want to have it in one single formula without a macro.

```
B   C
------
2   0
1   2
2   1
2   3
0   1
1   2
0   1
3   3
0   2
0   2
```

i have tried it with:

```
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(B3:B100;B3:B100>=C3:C100))} to get 1 for B
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(C3:C100;C3:C100>=B3:B100))} to get 7 for C
```

I excpected it to deliver me the longest series where the value in the one column was bigger than in the other one, but i failed hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version to get 7

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(C3:C100>=B3:B100,IF(B3:B100<>"",ROW(B3:B100))),IF(C3:C100<B3:B100,ROW(B3:B100))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

obviously reverse the ranges to get your other result

See example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52cd66zpb4ekmhp/max_freq.xlsx)

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for fast answer, but this formula returned me 15, where it should have returned 3.
i dont understand your C3:C100<B3:B1 ... i entered it also with ctrl+shift+enter. Maybe i was on the wrong path with the frequency formula or just have to write the macro...

Do i need to drag down the formula? because i tested it dragging it down for some rows, and it just counted down with sometimes decrementing with 0.

Comment: I attached an example workbook to my answer - you get 7 and 1 for your data as requested - you don't need to copy down, it's a single formula for the required result. The "data array" in FREQUENCY get the row numbers where your condition is matched, the bins are the other rows, so any value n in any bin represents a series, MAX then gets the MAX value of those, i.e. the longest series. You say you got 15 when you expected 3, on what data?

Comment: Thanks a lot Barry, you're awesome. I just had the translation wrong, i accidentially prior to other examples translated Rows into Columns...